# DeriveAnyClass vs Empty Instance

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, type-families, deriving

Suppose that I have this type family that throws a custom type error during compile time if the type passed to it is not a record:

```hs
type family IsRecord (a :: Type) where
  ...
```

Now I have this type class that has methods with default implementations, but requires that the type is a record, by adding the `IsRecord` constraint:

```hs
class IsRecord a => Foo a where
  foo :: Text
  foo = "foo"
```

When trying to use it incorrectly, if we use it as a regular instance with a type that is not a record, it successfully fails to compile:

```hs
data Bar = Bar

instance Foo Bar   -- error: Bar is not a record
```

But if I enable `-XDeriveAnyClass` and add it to the deriving clause, this doesn't fail to compile, ignoring completely the constraint:

```hs
data Bar = Bar
  deriving (Foo)
```

I understand that `DeriveAnyClass` generates an empty instance declaration, which is what I'm doing on the first example, but still it doesn't throw the error. What's going on?

I'm using GHC 8.6.4

Comment: It will "inherit" the constraint, like `instance IsRecord Bar => Foo Bar`.

Comment: Yeah, but that shouldn't compile, right?

Comment: why not? The constraint is false, but that is not a problem. If you later add the instance, in a module that uses this, then it becomes "available".

Comment: I understand that in practice this is not a problem, but my question goes towards *what* is the difference between those two things.

Comment: that you simply say that *if* `IsRecord Bar` holds, then we can define an `instance Foo Bar` as specified in that instance. For now that constraint does not hold, if you later add an instance, for example in *another* module, then the constraint is true, and hence you get an instance. It thus adds extra flexibility.

Comment: For example in the source code there are instance declarations like `instance HasCallStack => PrintStack` that are thus available, given the system uses a call stack. This instance is thus only avaiable then.

Comment: I see now, thanks! If you could post an answer, I can mark it as the solution. @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! I was going to mark this as a duplicate of [What is the difference between `DeriveAnyClass` and an empty instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39379006/791604), but it seems the behavior of GHC has changed since that question was asked and answered!

Anyway, if you ask -- either with `:i` inside ghci or with `-ddump-deriv` before starting ghci -- what the compiler has done, it's clear what the difference is in your case:

```
> :i Bar
data Bar = Bar  -- Defined at test.hs:15:1
instance IsRecord Bar => Foo Bar -- Defined at test.hs:16:13
```

Indeed, if you change the non-`DeriveAnyClass` version of your code to match, writing

```
instance IsRecord Bar => Foo Bar
```

instead of

```
instance Foo Bar
```

everything works fine. The details of how this instance context was chosen seem a bit complicated; you can read what the GHC manual has to say about it [here](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-any-other-class), though I suspect the description there is either not quite precise or not complete, as I don't get the same answer the compiler does here if I strictly follow the rules stated at the documentation. (I suspect the *true* answer is that it writes the instance first, then just does the usual type inference thing and copies any constraints it discovers in that way into the instance context.)